# Uma variável sem atribuir valor acessa o valor de variável em outra função

Tags: c, variáveis

Estou com uma atividade de Linguagem de Programação para fazer, cujo o código é feito na linguagem C, e nesta questão, a pergunta é:

> Qual será o retorno desse código e por que?

Eu não entendi porque uma função pegou o valor da variável da outra.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void set() {
char str[12] = "O rato roeu";
}

void show() {
char vet[12];
printf("vet = '%s'\n", vet);
}

int main() {
set();
show();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que esta sendo imprimido ?

Comment: -> " vet = 'O rato roeu' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entenda como funciona a [pilha de de memória e de chamadas de funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Este código funciona, mas está errado. Ele se aproveita de um comportamento que não pode ser garantido. Por pura coincidência a variável `str` de `show()` foi alocada no mesmo lugar da variável `str` de `set()`. Por causa disto funciona, mas se mudar um pouco este código a coincidência não ocorre e pegará um lixo de memória. Tecnicamente já está pegando lixo, mas é um lixo que era o que queria, então parece estar tudo ok.

Quando o código declara uma variável local de uma função isto é colocado na primeira posição possível da pilha. Quando volta para a função chamadora, a indicação da pilha retrocede indicando que o que tem ali não é mais necessário e que qualquer nova alocação na pilha deve ocorrer no ponto anterior. Isso é útil porque deixa as alocações de memória muito rápidas. Quando chama a outra função ela precisa alocar memória. Onde vai alocar? No mesmo lugar que tinha alocado na outra função. Aí se você acessar esta variável, pega o valor que já estava lá, até porque C não apaga a memória por conta própria.

Basta mudar isto e já verá problemas:

```
int x = 0;
char vet[12];
printf("vet = '%s'\n", vet);
printf("x = %d", x);
```

Veja ["funcionando" no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Crh5ba). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cxwzjenw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Stack.c).

Comment: Entendi, valeu mano!

Comment: +1 por "mas está errado" =-  ele está "muito errado" - e se a pergunta fi numa prova oulista de exercícios, o autor deveria perder sua "licença de programar' por uns 12 meses para reabilitação.

Esse código potencialmente avança sobre areas de memória não reservadas para o programa - e num sistema operacional numa máquina graned - tipo PC, em que a CPU temm MMU, etc, deveria terminar com segmentation fault - mas numa máquina de 8 bits - como um Arduino, ou um antigo APPLE 2,, ou mesmo um PC antigo com até Windows 98, poderia travar a máquina.

Comment: Pode dizer para o seu professor que "as pessoas na Internet" disseram para não fazer isso.

Comment: @jsbueno adoraria que tivesse licença pra programar :D

Comment: eu não, Pra mm progrmar é pra todo mundo. Mas algumas pessoas deveriam ter  a mesma caçada  - tipo - uma "licença negativa" para NÂO programar.